# Install heroku cli on linux *without* root, and *no auto update*

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface

I am a CS professor trying to teach web app development (Flask, Rails, SparkJava, etc.) using Heroku.

Our computing environment is a centrally managed Linux system, where neither the students nor I, have root permission. The students also have a very limited file and disk quotas: 200MB of space, and 4000 individual files.

I used to be able to provide them a way to give them access to the Heroku toolbelt by hacking the "standalone install" to get around the default assumption that the person doing the install has root permission.

But it is no longer working. When I install into a directory and run from there, the Heroku toolbelt keeps trying to "auto-update" into the ~/.local/share for *each individual user*  and since the Heroku-CLI installation has over 12000 files in it (!) it blows their file quota.

This is madness. I want to have just ONE installation of the Heroku toolbelt client, update it centrally and NOT have each student have to have their own copy. Is this too much to ask?  Is there any way to do this?

There used to be some trick to making the client think it was already up-to-date or some way to configure it to NOT do the auto-update. But I can't find how to do it.

(Thanks in advance for all of your good ideas such as: have them work on their own laptops, make a VM, have them work on AWS, etc. Those are all great ideas for some parallel universe in which they are feasible. If I *could* use any other computing environment, I'd already been doing that.  This is the one I have. If I can't make Heroku work here, I just can't use Heroku in class. And it's frustrating because it used to work.)

Comment: So, I just discovered a candidate workaround.  Still not sure if it will work, but it might.

In an instructor account with extra disk space and file allocation, I was able to update the cli under ./local/share/heroku    I then set the permissions on the instructor's home directory to 711, and recursively to 755 on ~instructor/.local    Finally, I symlinked from from ~student/.local/share/heroku to ~instructor/.local/share/heroku   

After that, the student account was able to run without it triggering auto updating.   At least for now.   I expect it will fail at some point.

Comment: Are you able to use docker on your *nix environment? If so, that would potentially be a good solution. You could build a small docker container that only contains the Heroku CLI tool by itself, and have the students use that CLI directly without needing to understand docker, containers, vms, etc. It would be pretty transparent to an end user.

Comment: I haven't tried, but given that the individual disk space quota is 200MB and their "number of files" quota is 4000, my guess is that docker is a non-starter.   I don't have enough experience with it to know for sure.

My little workaround seems to be getting the job done for the time being.

Comment: What is going to happen if they update their servers / API and you don't update the client? It will probably stop working...

Answer (score 1):

As a quick and dirty solution you can in `lib/heroku/updater.rb` change

```
def self.needs_update?
  compare_versions(latest_version, latest_local_version) > 0
end
```

to

```
def self.needs_update?
  false
end
```

and you will not be bugged with updates anymore. You have to do this each time you want to update manually.

A better more maintainable solution would be to get a config value or something similar for controlling this behavior accepted upstream in the toolbelt, which is open source at https://github.com/heroku/heroku